# Questions surrounding hacker rank 30 days of code, Day 6 [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays

Currently doing Hackerrank.com's 30 days of code and chose to do it in C++.

![day 6] https://imgur.com/a/euGFr

the image above is the question as well as my solution and the output which despite matching their output says it's incorrect. I'm new at C++ and wanted some tips as to how I could improve the code. I realize there are a multitude of different ways of rewriting it but simply wanted a critique of what I came up with and if it's overcomplicated or a suitable solution given the problem. thanks

for those that can't see the image this is the question:
TASK
Given a string,S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as  space-separated strings on a single line.
Input is the number of test cases(t) followed by a 't' number of strings. 
INPUT
2
Hacker
Rank
OUTPUT
Hce akr
Rn ak

MY CODE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int testCases;
    cin >> testCases;
    for(int i=0;i<testCases;i++)
    {
        char* evenArr = new char[0];
        char* oddArr = new char[0];
        string test;
        cin >> test;
        for(int j=0;j<test.length();j++)
        {
            if(j%2==0)
            {
                evenArr[j]=test[j];
                cout<<evenArr[j];
            }
            else
                oddArr[j]=test[j];
        }
        cout<<" ";
        for(int k = 0;k<sizeof(oddArr);k++)
        {
            cout << oddArr[k];
        }
        cout<<endl;
        delete[] evenArr;
        delete[] oddArr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new char[0]` seems not very appropriate.

Comment: Debug, debug, debug...

Comment: If you were trying to make a question as difficult to understand as possible, you've succeeded.

Comment: @RiberoD07 This output rnk ak is wrong. There should be rn ak

Comment: Post code & text, not screen snapshots.  Firewalls are blocking me from seeing your snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you started to use `std::string` use it instead of dynamically allocated char array (which you did wrong anyway, size should not be 0):

```
std::string split[2];
for( size_t i = 0; i < test.length(); ++i )
    split[i%2] += test[i];
```

another solution would be to pass `test` string twice and print even and odd symbols without temp strings:

```
for( size_t start : { 0, 1 } ) {
    for( size_t i = start; i < test.length(); i += 2 )
        std::cout << test[i];
    if( start == 0 ) 
        std::cout << ' ';
}
```